# Transparent Video in HTML 5 with Captivate

Tags: html, video, adobe-captivate

So I have shot some video on a green screen, removed the background in After Effects and have saved the video in an alpha channel. I want to place the video into Adobe Captivate, these video are going to be a talking narrative throughout the slides. After importing and placing the video where I want it, I go to preview. If I preview the slides in Captivates normal previewer the background is transparent, just the way I want it. But if I preview it or publish it to HTML 5 the background becomes black. HTML 5 is what this project needs to be viewed in. Am I doing something wrong or does HTML 5 not support transparent video. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use canvas element for rendering video with transparency, see https://github.com/m90/seeThru

> **seeThru - HTML5 video with alpha channel transparencies**
>
> This package adds "support" for the lacking alpha channel in HTML5  elements. The original video data will simply be re-rendered into a canvas-element, therefore adding the possibility to use transparencies for your video. Alpha information can either be included in the video's source file (moving) or in a seperate -element (static).

Comment: Is this cross browser friendly? I have the same issue. I need a video with transparency to be displayed with html5 video. Does this mean I cannot deliver to my client?

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero I haven't tried it but looking at the README of that repo: the browser has to support `<video>` and `<canvas>` elements. It's not working on mobile Webkit / Safari / Android Browser (yet).